# Insert song in R studio

Tags: r, audio

**I need help to insert this song into R 
http://www.thewavsite.com/Christmas/Jingle%20Bell%20Rock%20-%20Bobby%20Helms.wav**

'''library("audio")

song_file <- tempfile()

download.file("library("audio")

song_file <- tempfile()

download.file("http://www.thewavsite.com/Christmas/Jingle%20Bell%20Rock%20-%20Bobby%20Helms.wav", 
              bday_file, mode = "wb")

song <- load.wave(bday_file)

play(song)", 
              song_file, mode = "wb")

song <- load.wave(song_file)

play(song)'''

**And I get this error: Error in load.wave(song_file) : not a WAVE format**

Comment: You have two completely different urls. The one in the question is valid, but in code is invalid (404)

Comment: library("audio")

song_file <- tempfile()
download.file("http://www.thewavsite.com/Christmas/Jingle%20Bell%20Rock%20-%20Bobby%20Helms.wav", 
              bday_file, mode = "wb")
song_file<- load.wave(song_file)
play(song)

Comment: I made mistake when I posted a question, there are codes, but however still is error.